# Flutter web : Not being able to build flutter web project despite being able to run it in debug and release mode

Tags: flutter, dart

when try to build flutter web project with command:

flutter build web --web-renderer html --release

despite being able to run it in debug and release mode

I will get error :

```
Target dart2js failed: Exception: Uncaught exception in diagnostic handler: FormatException: Unexpected extension byte (at offset 0)
#0      _Utf8Decoder.convertSingle (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1747:7)
#1      Utf8Decoder.convert (dart:convert/utf.dart:351:42)
#2      Utf8BytesSourceFile.slowText (package:compiler/src/io/source_file.dart:201:10)
#3      SourceFile.lineStarts (package:compiler/src/io/source_file.dart:66:55)
#4      SourceFile.kernelSource (package:compiler/src/io/source_file.dart:32:9)
#5      SourceFile.getLocationMessage (package:compiler/src/io/source_file.dart:113:37)
#6      FormattingDiagnosticHandler.report (package:compiler/src/source_file_provider.dart:259:20)
#7      Compiler.callUserHandler.<anonymous closure> (package:compiler/src/compiler.dart:895:17)
#8      CompilerTask.measure (package:compiler/src/common/tasks.dart:66:51)
#9      Compiler.callUserHandler (package:compiler/src/compiler.dart:894:23)
#10     Compiler._reportDiagnosticMessage (package:compiler/src/compiler.dart:886:7)
#11     Compiler.reportDiagnostic (package:compiler/src/compiler.dart:873:5)
#12     DiagnosticReporter._reportDiagnostic (package:compiler/src/diagnostics/diagnostic_listener.dart:122:15)
#13     DiagnosticReporter.onError (package:compiler/src/diagnostics/diagnostic_listener.dart:266:11)
#14     Compiler.run.<anonymous closure> (package:compiler/src/compiler.dart:241:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#15     main (package:compiler/src/dart2js.dart:1473:3)
<asynchronous suspension>

The compiler crashed: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..51: 52
#0      _StringBase.[] (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:258:41)
#1      buildJsInteropBootstrap.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
(package:compiler/src/js_backend/js_interop_analysis.dart:31:58)
```

In my test I used web (Chrome) as my target platform.

Thank you for your help.